# Converting number format and comparing the file

Tags: conversion, file-comparison

I have a file with 174 fields. The first 4 fields are given below

```
1|2.3|2.3|34
1|0|0|34
1|0.0|0.0|34
1|11|11|34
1|.3|.3|34
1|-0.00|-0.00|34
1|1.67|1.67|34
```

I need to convert it into this:

```
1|2.30|2.30|34
1|0.00|0.00|34
1|0.00|0.00|34
1|11.00|11.00|34
1|0.30|0.30|34
1|0.00|0.00|34
1|1.67|1.67|34
```

I used the following but the last value came as `1|1.70|1.70|34`.

```
awk 'BEGIN {OFS=FS="|"} {$2=$2+0.00;$3=$3+0.00; print $0 }' file1 > temp1
awk 'BEGIN {OFS=FS="|"} {$2=sprintf("%.2f",$2);$3=sprintf("%.2f",$3);print $0}' temp1 > temp2
```

Answer (score 4):

With the `numfmt` utility from GNU Coreutils:

```
numfmt --delimiter='|' --field=2-3 --format='%.2f' < file
1|2.30|2.30|34
1|0.00|0.00|34
1|0.00|0.00|34
1|11.00|11.00|34
1|0.31|0.31|34
1|0.00|0.00|34
1|1.67|1.67|34
```

Adjust the field range `--field=2-3` according to your requirements

Comment: Oooh. That's a useful tool.

Comment: @roaima I discovered it on here iirc - it can do all kinds of unit conversions as well, but I haven't delved into that

Answer (score 0):

Your second `awk` construct is almost perfect. Try this

```
awk -F'|' 'BEGIN {OFS = FS} {$2 = sprintf("%0.2f", $2+0); $3 = sprintf("%0.2f", $3+0); print $0}'
1|2.30|2.30|34
1|0.00|0.00|34
1|0.00|0.00|34
1|11.00|11.00|34
1|0.30|0.30|34
1|0.00|0.00|34
1|1.67|1.67|34
```

Comment: I have 174  fields. For sample I have give 3 fields